# Python: input validation not working

Tags: python, validation, if-statement

I have this code:

```
#counting the number down to zero.
x = int(x)
while x>=0:
    print x
    x -= 1

#if the user asks for a number below zero print this:
if x<0:
    print "You cant countdown number below zero."

#if the user asks for something else than a number print this:
else:
    print "only insert numbers."
```

The code itself is really basic, just counting a random number down till zero.
The only problem is that my else block is not working, I made the else block for when someone writes a word/letter instead of a number. Can anyone please solve this problem? :)

EDIT: 
The error that I am getting is:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ha'
```

Comment: You should state in your question exactly how it's not working. What is going wrong? What kind of output are you getting? What kind of output do you want to get?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct tabulations?

Comment: `else` part will be never executed because the code subtract number till it became negative one.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a different approach. First validate the input:

```
try:
    x = int(x)
except ValueError:
    print "only insert numbers"
    #return from function, or exit the program, or whatever you want

while x >= 0:
    print x
    x -= 1

if x < 0:
    print "You cant countdown number below zero."
```

Comment: Python comments are `#`, not `//`.